# Weird spaces inside tables or centering of text inside tables

Tags: tables

[image: Image of the issue]I am having issues with the text in my (landscaped) table creating large white spaces in the cells. In the middle column after my text and in the last column before text, as well as the location of the equations in the left column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    
\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\caption{Foo bar}
\label{tab:Foobar}
\begin{tabular}{|p{70mm}|p{60mm}|p{110mm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Equation} & \textbf{Conditions} & \textbf{Notes} \\ \hline
\begin{equation}
    \overline{\text{A}} = 3
\end{equation}          & \makecell{Foo bar \\ Foo bar \\ Foo bar \\ Foo bar \\ Foo bar} & Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\ \hline
\begin{equation}
    \overline{\text{B}} = 4
\end{equation}          & \makecell{Foo bar \\ Foo bar \\ Foo bar \\ Foo bar} & \lipsum[1-1] \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to add a screenshot

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I suggest you change both instances of `\makecell{...}` to `\makecell[t]{...}`.

Comment: Off-topic: You should also change `\text{A}` and `\text{B}` to `\mathrm{A}` and `\mathrm{B}`, respectively.

Comment: you are fixing the wide column widths `\begin{tabular}{|p{70mm}|p{60mm}|p{110mm}|`  why not let the first two columns just be the size of the entries `llp{110mm}`

Answer (score 0):

It was eventually an issue with `\makecell{}`, changing it to `\makecell[t]{}` solved the problem. The details of how, I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

- Your code example is not compilable, you forgot to load package `amsmath`
- Size of table columns are bad selected. Table protrude right landscape page border ....
- From package documentation follows that default position of `\makecell` content in table cell is vertical and horizontal centered. This you can change locally by adding options `t` or `b` for mowing baseline of `makecell` content )(to top or to bottom) and `l` or `r` for horizontal positions  and align of a `makecell` content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Foo bar}
\label{tab:Foobar}

\begin{tabular}{|p{60mm}|p{60mm}|p{60mm}|}
    \hline
\textbf{Equation}   & \textbf{Conditions} & \textbf{Notes} \\ \hline
\begin{equation}
    \overline{\text{A}} = 3
\end{equation}      & \makecell{Foo bar \\ Longer foo bar \\ Very long foo bar \\ Foo bar} 
                        & Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar 
                            \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}
\caption{Foo bar with baseline at top}
\label{tab:Foobar}

\begin{tabular}{|p{60mm}|p{60mm}|p{60mm}|}
    \hline
\textbf{Equation}   & \textbf{Conditions} & \textbf{Notes} \\ \hline
\begin{equation}
    \overline{\text{A}} = 3
\end{equation}      & \makecell[t]{Foo bar \\ Longer foo bar \\ Very long foo bar \\ Foo bar} 
                        & Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar 
                            \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
        
    \begin{table}
\caption{Foo bar with baseline at bottom and left aligned}
\label{tab:Foobar}

\begin{tabular}{|p{60mm}|p{60mm}|p{60mm}|}
    \hline
\textbf{Equation}   & \textbf{Conditions} & \textbf{Notes} \\ \hline
\begin{equation}
    \overline{\text{A}} = 3
\end{equation}      & \makecell[bl]{Foo bar \\ Longer foo bar \\ Very long foo bar \\ Foo bar} 
                        & Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar 
                            \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This settings you can declare globally to by:

```
    \renewcommand\cellalign{<desired options>}
```

However (regardless that it is not known what is your intention with this table) simpler code and nicer result you can get by use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Foo bar}
\label{tab:tblr}


\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[c, wd=60mm] X[c] X[j]},
             row{1}  = {l, font=\bfseries}
             }
\textbf{Equation}   & \textbf{Conditions} & \textbf{Notes} \\
\begin{equation}
    \overline{\text{A}} = 3
\end{equation}      &   {Foo bar \\ Longer foo bar \\ Very long foo bar \\ Foo bar} 
                        & \lipsum[1][1-1]   \\ 
\begin{equation}
    \overline{\text{B}} = 4
\end{equation}      &   {Foo bar \\ Foo bar \\ Foo bar \\ Foo bar} 
                        & \lipsum[1][2-5]   \\ 
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}  
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]